# Which version of mongojs is compatible with node js version 10.15

Tags: mongojs

I am using mongojs version 2.6.0 with node version 10.15. How can I find out which mongodb version is being used?

The mongodb compatibility version mentions that >=3.0 version is required to work with node version 10.15